# Using question mark in Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, ibatis

I send request http://xxxx.com/test/?app_idx=80 via browser.

But the ibatis parses this wrong.

```
select
    CONCAT('http://localhost:8080/apps/icon/download/?app=', app_idx)
from test
where app_idx = ?;
```

---

I expected my query to be

```
select
    CONCAT('http://localhost:8080/apps/icon/download/?app=', app_idx)
from test
where app_idx = **80**;
```

But the real was 'http://localhost:8080/apps/icon/download/?app=80'.

```
select
    CONCAT('http://localhost:8080/apps/icon/download/80app=', app_idx)
from test
where app_idx = **?**;
```

Is there a way to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select CONCAT('?', app_idx)
from test
where app_idx = ?;
```

and pass

```
http://localhost:8080/apps/icon/download/?app=
```

as the first parameter.